# Text is cut off in textview at the left side of the screen in android device

Tags: android, textview

I'm facing a problem with arabic text in android device (LG optimus P970), the text is cut off at the left side of the device , i tried to use padding , decrease the width of the textview ...
Nothing works,what should i do?

[image]

```
And this is the layout :
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <LinearLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
android:layout_height="413dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingLeft="20dip"
android:paddingRight="20dip" 
android:id="@+id/details_page">


 <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dip" 
    >

     <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/details_text_id"
        android:gravity="right"         
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/iqraa_green" 

        />

  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you considered using a RelativeLayout instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to give width of textview smaller than display width

Answer (score 0):

i am found your problem is textview `android:gravity="right"`

Try this below xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                  <LinearLayout
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="@color/white" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="413dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip" 
    android:id="@+id/details_page">


     <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" 
        >

         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/details_text_id"
            android:gravity="left"         
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/iqraa_green" 

            />

      </ScrollView>
```

i am change the textview gravity right to left like below code:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

instead of

```
android:gravity="left"
```

Comment: right side alignment align correct,example if u open word document type some paragraphs and align paragraph to right also align like your textview!

Comment: is there another way to solve this issue rather than changing the Gravity?

Comment: this is not issue right side alignment are align like your textview!

Comment: you try can change gravity left to align a text!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years later but for anyone who comes across this you can do this by adding

```
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
```

To your TextView

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/details_text_id"
        android:gravity="left"         
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/iqraa_green"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" 

        />
```

This is because the style tells the scrollbar to draw outside of your padding rather than the default which is inside. You may also be able to use outsideInset style.

More [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle)